# Class accessors and inheritance in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, class-variables

Like the following code shows, having class accessors defined in the superclass could have unexpected behaviours because the class accessor is the same variable for all the subclasses.

```
class Super 
  cattr_accessor :name
end

class SubA < Super; end
class SubB < Super; end

SubA.name = "A"
SubB.name = "B"

SubA.name
 => "B" # unexpected!
```

I want to have an independent class accessor for each subclass, so a possible solution is moving the cattr_accessor from the superclass and putting it in every subclass.

```
class Super; end

class SubA < Super
  cattr_accessor :name
end

class SubB < Super
  cattr_accessor :name
end

SubA.name = "A"
SubB.name = "B"

SubA.name
 => "A" # expected!
```

It is this solution a good practice? Do you know better alternatives?

Comment: This is expected behaviour. One is an attribute of `Super`, which is inherited by it's children. The other is an attribute of the child class, which overrides the inherited value. --- One question, tho: Will this value ever be changed? Class variables are often the wrong solution, consider if it should be a constant, or an instance variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open up `Super`'s singleton class and give that a regular `attr_accessor`:

```
class Super 
  class << self
    attr_accessor :name
  end
end
```

That should give you the semantics you want: a "class level instance variable".

However I'll note that any value set for `:name` on `Super` will not be inherited by `Super`'s children.  This makes sense if you think about it: the children inherit the `attr_accessor`, not the attribute itself.

There are some ways around this, most notably rails provides [`class_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/class_attribute) which provides the ability of children to inherit the value of the parent's attribute unless explicitly overridden.

Comment: Thanks. I think class_attribute is the way to go for this case.